# Verify the inequality of $\infty$ norm, $L^\infty$ norm and $L^1$ norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, normed-spaces

Denote $P_n[0,h]$ to be the set of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ on the interval $[0,h]$. SHow that there exist two positive constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ **independent** of $h$ and $u$ such that for any $u\in P_n[0,h]$,
\begin{equation}
C_1h\|u\|_\infty\leq\|u\|_{L^1}\leq C_2h\|u\|_{L^\infty}.
\end{equation}

I'm confused about $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and $\|u\|_{L^\infty}$. Are they the same?

If my understanding is correct, $\|\cdot\|_{L^\infty}=\max_{x\in[0,h]}|u(x)|$, then $\|u\|_{L^1}=\int_0^h|u|dx\leq\int_0^h\max_{x\in[0,h]}|u|dx=h\|u\|_{L^\infty}$. Letting $C_2=1$ is just enough. Is it correct? If it is, what about the left inequality?

Comment: If $\|\cdot\|_\infty=\|\cdot\|_{L^\infty}$, then the left inequality is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion. You should (a) prove the inequalities in $P_n[0,1]$ and then (b) get the usual version by change of variables.

(a) is easy since every two norms are equivalent in finite dimensional spaces

(b) Using that if $f(x)=g(hx)$, then 
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) dx=\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h g(t)dt 
$$